# How to determine if this script was included into some other script

Tags: php

Some time ago, I developed a PHP script to send text messages, log sms usage, and so on.  This is working fine.

Now I have modified it so that it may be included within another script via "include" or "require."  Again it is working fine but I would like to make it operate slightly differently if "included" versus the command-line call.  For example, if it's called from command line, then the parameters are in $argv, but if included in some function, we can assume certain necessary variables have already been set up, SQL connections are established, etc.

The point where I'm stuck, is trying to determine if this code is "include"d or is the main file.  I know I can use get_included_files() to retrieve the necessary list.  But at present (assuming my script is /path/myscript) the only test I know to use is something like:

```
$includes = get_included_files() ;
$isMainScript = ($includes[0] == '/path/myscript') ;
```

And therefore $isMainScript will be true if this was called from the command line.  But clearly this is bad form; all one has to do to break it, is to rename the included script, or move it to some other directory.  But I don't see any method of finding out the name of *this* file (/path/myscript) ... only the name of the main file (`__FILE__` and its workalikes).

What do others do in order to determine if this script is a main script, or is subordinate to some other?

Comment: I suggest you split the original code into two scripts. One is an include file that just defines functions. The original script includes this file and calls the functions. Then other scripts can also include the file and call the functions.

Comment: If 'we can assume certain necessary variables have already been set up' if it is included, then just instantiate $somestupidvariablename in the other script(s) and test for it with if(isset($somestupidvariablename)) in this script;

Comment: To expand on what Barmar has said, you should consider what you have to be two separate things: the "library" code that defines the generally-useful functionality, and the "implementation" code that ties it to a certain workflow. In this case it would be SMS _library_ code, and then CLI [or other] _implementation_ code.

Comment: Makes good sense, @Barmar.  If you make your comment into an answer, I will accept it.  Thanks to all who replied.